# Can you put a TextFormField inside a Dismissible widget?

Tags: flutter, textformfield, dismissible

I am trying to put a TexFormField widget inside of a dismissible widget and be able to dismiss the row when the there is a cursor active inside the TextFormField.

If the TextFormField does not have focus and you swipe to delete it works just fine. If you have focus on the TextFormField and swipe to delete the row, onDismissed is never called.

I have tried tracing what is happening with the debugger and it seems like the dismissible widget is getting unmounted for some reason.

To reproduce simply put a TextFormField inside a Dismissible widget and see if you can get onDismissed to be called when the TextFormField has focus.

Comment: Can you include sample code

Comment: Can you share your code. So, we can look at the code and help you out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.